# how to build asmack library for android

Tags: android, xmpp, smack, asmack

I Don't find how to build asmack library for android from the below git hub asmack build environment

```
https://github.com/flowdalic/asmack
```

Comment: https://github.com/siacs/Conversations

Comment: https://github.com/redsolution/xabber-android

Comment: Thanks for your comment,Xabber unable to use as library project so I am looking for asmack build

Comment: r u want to creat chatting app in android

Comment: http://overwatering.org/blog/2013/05/compiling-asmack/
Yes wanted to created chatting app with xmpp server

Comment: https://github.com/chunjiangshieh/android-demo-xmpp-androidpn

Comment: Yes i have seen is it better solution for chatting app with xmpp

Comment: sorry i m going to home my mail id er.naveen.tamrakar@gmail.com any query for chating than mail me

Comment: my chatting app https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.krave.kraveapp